# Doctrine2: Updating a One-To-Many association with an ArrayCollection doesn't delete items

Tags: doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine2, a `Note` entity has a One-To-Many association with a `File` entity. So, a note can have many Files associated with.

Then, consider the following code:

```
/*
 * @entityManager : this is a pre-obtained EntityManager object
 * @notes : expects a Note entity
 * @filesId : expects an array of integer representing file ids
 */
function setNoteFiles($entityManager, $note, $filesId) {
    $files = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($filesId as $fileId) {
        $file = $entityManager->find('File', $fileId);
        $file->setNote($note);
        $files->add($file);
    }
    $note->setFiles($files);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

So, when I want to add files to a note, such as using the following, it works perfectly as expected:

```
setNoteFiles($entityManager, $note, Array(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

But, if later I want to remove one file in the collection, (without using removeElement, of course! I would like to set the `ArrayCollection` itself), like this:

```
setNoteFiles($entityManager, $note, Array(1, 2, 4));
```

Then, this doesn't work. In the database, the foreign key column doesn't get updated (nulled or zero'ed) for this file record.

Isn't Doctrine supposed to managed the new ArrayCollection to add the items and remove the ones that are no longer needed?